# What brand is this 3-handle tub faucet set it?

Tags: faucet, tub

I'm looking to replace the current tub & shower faucets but need to know the right brand!

Comment: No image showing.

Comment: Are you asking which brand you should purchase?

Answer (score 1):

If you are, indeed, replacing the entire faucet, it does not matter what brand they are - only the spacing matters assuming you need to match the existing holes in the wall. If you are repairing the wall, you may simply replace them without concern for the current brand or spacing.

If you are replacing internal parts (only) then it might matter.